# Get cursor position in a contenteditable div using innerHTML and pipes

Tags: html, angular, contenteditable, caret

I'm writing a simple WYSIWYG editor in Angular 5 to handle tags in the text. Those tags are like variables. For instance when doing: `Hi (!--username--), welcome!` it's rendered as `Hi alex, welcome!`. In order to be user-friendly for the non-technical, the WYSIWYG is transforming `(!--username--)` to a pretty HTML fragment showing directly "Alexandre" in its content.

This editor needs to handle simple HTML tags too (`<b>`, `<i>`, ...)

To do that, I've developed a component named editor which is using Angular's value accessors and showing a simple div like that:

```
  <div class="editor" #editor [innerHTML]="content | prettytags: completions" (focus)="toogleToolbar()" (focusout)="toogleToolbar()"
    (click)="onClick($event)" (keyup)="onKey($event)" [attr.contenteditable]="!readonly"></div>
```

The pipe looks like (for information, `completions` is the variable containing all tags values):

```
const pattern: RegExp = /(\(!--[^\s-]*--\))/;

@Pipe({
  name: 'prettytags'
})
export class PrettyTagsPipe {

  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

  transform(value: string, completions: any[]): SafeHtml {
    if (isNil(value)) return '';
    const text = this.makeText(value, completions, 0);
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(text);
  }

  private makeText(value: string, completions: any[], index: number): any {
    const text = value
      .split(pattern)
      .map(word => {
        const tag = completions.find(t => t.tag === word);
        return isNil(tag)
          ? word
          : this.getTagHtml(tag.value)
      })
      .join('');

    return text;
  }

  private getTagHtml(text: any) {
    return `<span class="chip" spellcheck="false">${text}</span>&nbsp;`;
  }
}
```

In order to get the two-way data binding working as I'm using [innerHTML], I'm using the keyup event to get new characters but I need to get the caret position to append new characters. To do that I've copy/pasted a function found on Stack Overflow to get the caret position:

```
  private getCaretPosition() {
    const element = document.querySelector('.editor');
    const range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    const preCaretRange = range.cloneRange();
    preCaretRange.selectNodeContents(element);
    preCaretRange.setEnd(range.endContainer, range.endOffset);
    return preCaretRange.toString().length;
  }
```

And on my onKeyUp: I do the following:

```
[...]
const position = this.getCaretPosition();
this.content += key.length === 1 ? this.content.slice(0, position) + key + this.content.slice(position) : '';
```

but it's not working as it gets the text position.

For instance, if the user wants to edit the content: from `Hi (!--username--), welcome!` to `Hi (!--username--), I'm fine to see you back!`, he will place his caret just after the comma, so I'll get `8` (for "Hi alex,") but with my content variable I'll get `Hi (!--u`.

I know I can get the position of the cursor with HTML tags, but I'll need to do many computations for each key pressed.

Do you have any idea to get this thing to work?

Comment: Hi did you resolve this ?

Comment: Hi! Yes. https://github.com/timdown/rangy helped me a lot.

Comment: Do you have a open github for your project, keen to check your project out

Comment: Sorry but I can't. It's a business project.

Comment: ok no worries. thanks